# Getchar() infinite loop

Tags: c, input, eof, getchar

I’m starting to learn from "The C Programing Language" and one of the codes in the book is not working for me. This code suppose to count the number of characters using `getchar()`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  long nc;

  nc = 0;
  while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
  printf("%1d\n", nc);

  return 0;
}
```

I try to run it and write some characters but when I press `ENTER`, it only starts a new line. It's like it’s never getting out of the loop.

Comment: Is that really the code from the book, as is? `getchar != EOF` and not `getchar() != EOF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A newline is not an `EOF`. You’re confusing `EOF` and `EOL`.

When your press `ENTER`, `getchar()` receives a newline: `\n`, and your program counts it just like any other character.

Try pressing `CTRL` + `D` (Linux terminal) or `CTRL` + `Z` (Windows terminal) to send **an empty input** to your program, thus ending it.

You can also write your input to a file, and give this file to your program as input, like this:

```
./your_program < your_file
```

When your input comes from a file, an `EOF` is automatically sent to your program when reaching the end of the file. That’s because there is not more output to get from the file.